# Javascript scroll event cross browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, scroll

In my project i need to grab some parameters related to scroll event on a page like start datetime, stop datetime, ycoords on start scrolling and ycoords on stop.
I need to trap only the start and stop of the scroll events but i know that in JavaScript there isn't methods for this purpose.
Any idea for doing it with all major browser compatibility?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may want to consider getting information about other events instead of "scroll" such as touchstart/touchend, for example, for touch or similar events for mouse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/hYsRh/4/

```
    $(window).scroll($.debounce( 250, true, function(){
        $('#scrollMsg').html('SCROLLING!');
    }));
    $(window).scroll($.debounce( 250, function(){
        $('#scrollMsg').html('DONE!');
    }));
```

[jQuery debounce](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/)

Comment: plugins are not always the way to go!

Comment: What i often do, is if i don't need the whole plugin, i check how the method i need works. Here debounce. Just need to check the debounce methode and make rearrange it to your code. It's the easiest way to learn things :3